# Wrong element loaded in firefox and edge, chrome works fine

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking at this codepen http://codepen.io/ariona/pen/JYGzBB.

If loaded in chrome the first card that displays in the 'overview' card. But in firefox and edge it doesn't load correctly.

Is there a way to fix this? (javascript below)

```
$(".card-toggle").on("click", function(){

// Card toggle state    
$(".card-toggle").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");

var isAnimating = false;

if( !isAnimating ){
    isAnimating = true;

    $(".card").find(".card-content").css("z-index",0);
    $(".card").removeClass("active");

    var that = $(this);

    $(this).siblings().css("z-index",1);

    setTimeout(function(){
        that.parent().toggleClass("active").find(".card-content").on("transitionend", function(){
            isAnimating = false;
        }); ;

    },10);
} else {
    return;
}
 });

$(".contact").on("click",function(){
$(".contact-form").toggleClass("active");
 });
 $(".contact-form input[type=submit], .contact-form .close").on("click",function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$(".contact-form").toggleClass("active")
 });
```

Comment: Does the page/card need script to load properly?

Comment: That's jQuery not javascript >.>